# Lookup function for large list of floats - memoized computation?

Tags: c#, f#

I need to write a lookup function for a large list (float*float). This function should add a new entry if key is not found or sum values if key is found. I have read about memoized computations and actually it wasnt really that hard to do. Here is what I have:

```
let memoLookUp basearr lookarr =
    let t = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<float,float>()
    for (a,b) in basearr do
        t.Add(a,b)
    for (a, b) in lookarr do
        if t.ContainsKey(a) then t.[a] <- t.[a] + b
        else t.Add(a,b)
    t
```

Sample data:

```
let basearr = [(41554., 10.0) ; (41555., 11.0) ; (41556., 12.0) ; (41557., 10.0) ; (41558., 13.0) ]

let lookarr = [(41555., 14.0) ; (41556., 15.0) ; (41559., 16.0)]
```

This returns as expected.

My questions are:

- if the lists are long (say about 30000 each) is it sensible to do this this way from a performance point of view?
- Or would it be better to sort by the date (in column one of each data list) and then use a more imperative approach?
- Or is there even sth build in in f# or c#?

Comment: Hi, this is a great topic for functional, and actually, computation in general. however, it seems that there are many things at stake in your  exemple. you 'memoize' only part of the computation as you want update the result back. memoization itself does not work with destructive code, as it is based on the idea that the same argument should lead to the same value out, which is not the case here. so it would be really useful to dig in what you really want to do : is it to reuse previous computation already done and just add the incremental bit (the 1 addition) you want ?

Comment: I need to do exactly what it does, i.e. lookup the key (here date) and if it is hit then add the value in the lookarr to basearr, if it is a miss then add both the date and the value to the list

Comment: and you want to do it just once, not compose these operations ?

Comment: I dont understand. I have two arrays input and one array as output that combined the input in relevant way. Once this is done I dont need to redo this, unless I reapply the function to a new dataset

Comment: trying to help you out, man. your code has assumption (like basearr has unique keys..), so it is interesting to understand *why* you do something, not *what* you do

Comment: nicolas: I really appreciate your help! just didnt understand you. I m no expert programmer and I did it this way because I could think of this way and it sounded kind of elegant. What would you suggest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your existing code might usefully merge the two arrays to have a more uniform behaviour. unless otherwise needed, (for instance, you ***want*** the program to crash if basearr contains duplicate) uniform is better

```
let incrementalAdderImperative aseq = 
  let d= System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<_,_>()
  Seq.iter(fun (k,v) ->  if d.ContainsKey(k) 
                         then d.[k] <- d.[k] + v
                         else d.Add(k,v)) aseq
```

To answer your questions :

- > if the lists are long (say about 30000 each) is it sensible to do
  >   this this way from a performance point of view?

You are using hash based dictionary, by relying on the Dictionary class. so it should not degrade at all. Note that this is a property of this *implementation* of dictionaries, not of the functionality of dictionaries, described in IDictionary. there are other implementations (for instance Map)

If you are concerned about performance, you should initialize your dictionary with a (fast) estimate of how many keys will happen to avoid internal resizing. and know the concrete types used (like a Hash-based dictionary, etc..)

- > would it be better to sort by the date (in column one of each data
  >   list) and then use a more imperative approach?

If you sorted by the date, you could do a fold. I think this would be faster, but the number you mention are not that big.

```
let oneshotAdder reducer kvArr =
    kvArr |> Array.sortInPlaceBy fst
    let a = kvArr 
            |> Array.fold(fun (res) (k,v) ->  
                            match res with
                            | []                             -> (k,v)::res
                            | ((prevk,_)::xs) when k = prevk -> (k,reducer v (List.head res |> snd))::(List.tail res)
                            | _                              -> (k,v)::res)
                          List.empty
    dict a
let data = Array.concat ([basearr; lookarr] |> List.map List.toArray)
let dict2 = oneshotAdder (+) data
```

ps : in the example you give, basearr and lookarr are lists, not arrays, hence the extraneous operation assuming you indeed want to operate on arrays.

- > is there even sth build in in f# or c#?

In F#, you can do natively a groupby and them sum elements. the essence of collection transform is to pass functions around, so it is no surpise to have it natively.
In C#, you can use Linq to get such enumeration transforms, which under the hood map to some functions like in fsharp.

```
let groupByAdder reducer (kvArr:('k*'v) array)  =
    kvArr |> Seq.groupBy fst 
          |> Seq.map (fun (k,vs) -> k , vs |> Seq.map snd |> (Seq.reduce reducer)) 
          |> dict
let dict3 = groupByAdder (+) data
```

Comment: thanks nicolas. Great answer and I can learn a lot from it. In terms of performance you think the oneshotadder is fastest?

Comment: I would imagine it is the fastest.. but it also depends on your overall usage. In performance there are two rules : do not bother until (1. it is a problem) and (2.you have measure on where to improve). one small line can be the problem if executed many times. one network access can make an otherwise perfectly fine algo slow. one structure is fast when accessing recent items, but slow for general purpose. the perf depends very specifically in the overall pattern of usage. unlike the usual functional problem you dont reduce it downward to the base case : you compose it upward and measure !

Comment: case in point is the small level optimizations. an imperative program expressed in low level terms would make the loops very fast. a high level program would determine that it does not need to do (or redo) that loop...

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
Seq.groupBy fst kvs
|> Seq.map (fun (k, vs) -> k, Seq.map snd vs |> Seq.reduce (+))
|> dict
```

Comment: Thanks Jon. But I dont really get it. Do you mean the same as the last code snippet from Nicolas below?

Comment: Yes but simpler. Think of the input as a sequence of key-value pairs. Group them by key. Then sum all of the values associated with each key. Then put those key-total-value pairs in a dictionary for fast lookup by key.

Comment: I have very little occasion to correct Jon, who is more knowledgeable than me, so I'll take it this time. vs is actually a tuple, so you still need to map on the second component before adding :)